# How to get the OSX Style SimpleModal to work with dynamic linkbutton

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, dynamic, simplemodal

First, i have quickly become a huge fan of jQuery.  The simplicity has really caught my attention.  I am learning something new everyday working with jQuery as i have not been working with it for that long.  I have working with the SimpleModal and love its look and feel.  I have come across and issue though and was wondering if there was anyone who could help me with it.  I have a page that was originally making a call to the database retrieving data and populating a gridview with the data.  I had the OSX Style SimpleModal attached to a linkbutton in the gridview and that worked GREAT!!  However, ive decided to instead of having server-side code call the database, i will have an .ajax call which will retrieve the data.  Obviously i cannot populate the gridview with the data from the .ajax call so i decided to dynamically create a table with a link inside the table hoping it would have the ability to launch the OSX Style SimpleModal the same way the gridview link did.  But to my dismay, it did not.  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to get it to work or perhaps suggest a different technique for showing the data coming back from the .ajax call.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
  $('#cmdSubmit_Create').click(function () {
        var allowCodes;
        if ($('#chkAllowValueCodes').is(':checked')) {
            allowCodes = 1;
        }
        else {
            allowCodes = 0;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/createSource",
            data: '{"schoolId":"' + $('#ddSchools').val() + '","vendor":"' + $('#txtVendor').val() + '","tsource":"' + $('#txtTSource').val() + '","allowCodes":"' + allowCodes + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                document.getElementById('divResults').innerHTML = msg.d;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('error' + error)
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This is my code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string createSource(string schoolId, string vendor, string tsource, int allowCodes)
{
    try
    {
        dsResults = Common.CreateHandPSource(tsource, schoolId, vendor, allowCodes);

        return BuildTable(dsResults.Tables[0]);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not create source code!");
    }
}

public static string BuildTable(DataTable dt)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int colCount = dt.Columns.Count;

    sb.Append("<table><thead>");

    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append("<th>" + column.ColumnName + "</th>");
    }

    sb.Append("</thead><tbody>");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        do
        {
            sb.Append("<td>");

            if (y == 0)
            {
                sb.Append("<a href='#' class='osx'  OnClientClick='showFields(this)' >" + row["SchoolId"] + "-" + row["title"] + "</a>");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(row[y]);
            }

            sb.Append("</td>");
            y++;
        }
        while (y < colCount);
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        y = 0;
    }

    sb.Append("</tbody></table>");

    return sb.ToString();

}
```

SOLUTION:

I initialize the OSX modal on the live.hover of the link and that allows the link to launch the click function for the OSX SimpleModal.  Here is the code:

```
    $('.osx').live('hover', function () {
        OSX.init();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential problems...

1. You are telling the .ajax method that you expect a Json return but you are actually returning HTML.
2. Your data looks like a Json obect inside a string for some reason.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Test.aspx/createSource",
    data: { schoolId: $('#ddSchools').val(), vendor: $('#txtVendor').val(), tsource: $('#txtTSource').val(), allowCodes: allowCodes},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $('#divResults').clear().html(msg);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('error' + error)
    }
});
```